# git branch and git log only work with sudo

Tags: git, terminal

I'm having an issue where `git branch` and `git log` give no output unless I use them with `sudo`. Here is a screenshot showing the issue.

I'm on linux mint 19 with ecryptfs. I've tried two different terminal emulators and the problem persists. If there's any more information that you think would be helpful, please let me know.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQOUi.png)

Comment: Could there be content in `.git/` which your user does not have access to without privilege elevation?

Comment: Apparently not. I don't know if this is relevant, but `.git/branches` appears to be empty.

Comment: Seems very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52127324/7976758) problem. Discussion was moved to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179256/discussion-on-question-by-nikhil-why-do-i-need-root-privilege-to-do-git-branch). The problem seems to be with a pager. The workaround is to avoid pager: `git --no-pager branch`.

Comment: Amazing! Running `mv ~/anaconda3/bin/pager{,.bad}` worked like a charm. And such a relief that it wasn't a deeper issue.

Comment: This has come up a lot recently. There must be some issue with some Linux release and/or this anaconda3 thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your `.git` Directory is not readable by the current user. Run a `ls -la .git` and see what the permissions and owner for the directory `.` show.

Then you need to decide if you want to give your user permissions or ownership for the `.git` directory (and probably also the project files themselves)

Comment: Thanks! I get the following:

```drwxrwxr-x  8 jeffrey jeffrey  4096 Sep  5 09:04 .

drwxrwxr-x 13 jeffrey jeffrey  4096 Sep  5 08:52 ..```

[additional lines]

How do I fix this? This is also a problem I have over multiple repos.

Comment: It seems like the files are readable and writeable by you. So not really something to fix on that front considering that you're trying to work as user jeffrey. Guess i have no bright idea atm how to fix your problem. sorry